# Customer/Account don't allow edit password

Tags: customer, password

My Magento Users, use external system to login in my store.
So I would like, to disable some options in "Account Dashboard".

First, I need to disable allow to the user to change the password. ¿It's possible? What I've to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is many track of don't allow the change password.for example you remove change password link is so easy way using CSS.And you want to other way check this link-

**https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/How-to-stop-customers-changing-password/m-p/145285#M8952**

**`THANKS`**